# How can I get index with 'li' text on jQueryui-sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jqueryui-sortable. I want to get final result as an array.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="bizline-sortable-section ui-sortable">                   
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-slider</li>                    
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-quote</li>                 
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-service</li>                   
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-features</li>                  
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-testimonial</li>                   
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-team</li>                  
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-cta</li>                   
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-news</li>                  
</ul>
```

I want output afetr shot as:

```
[
  home-slider : final index,
  home-quote : final index,
  home-service : final index
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll(".bizline-sortable-section li")` to get all li elements, and perform some modifications:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".bizline-sortable-section li");
var texts = Array.from(elements).map(el => el.innerText);
var indexes = Object.fromEntries(texts.map(el => [el, texts.indexOf(el)]));
console.log(indexes);
```

```html
<ul class="bizline-sortable-section ui-sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-slider</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-quote</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-service</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-features</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-testimonial</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-team</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-cta</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">home-news</li>
</ul>
```